# Retrieve value of key when key is declared on java class

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-webflow

I am using spring web flow `2.5.0` along with thymeleaf `3.0.9`.

I have a class containing some static keys ex:

```
public class MyKeys{
 .....
 public static final String myKey = "myKey1"
 .....  
}
```

Somewhere in my controller I store a value for that key in order to be available in the template file.

(pseudo-code):

```
context.add(MyKeys.mykey,"screen.home.welcome");
```

`screen.home.welcome` is an i18n message key(store on application's `message.properties`) whose value I want to present to the user.

This works **but** I want to use the key from `MyKeys` class to access its value.

`<div th:utext="#{${myKey1}}"></div>`

What I have tried and **is not** working:

`<div th:utext="#{${T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey}}"></div>`

With this what I get in the template is `myKey1`. How I can instruct thymeleaf to retrieve the value which is associated to `myKey1`?

Comment: maybe `<div th:utext="#{'${T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey}'}"></div>` or `<div th:utext="#messages.msg('${T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey}')"></div>` or `<div th:utext="#messages.msg(T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey}"></div>`

Comment: @rptmat57 Unfortunately none of them is working, they all render `messages.msg`. The last one may contain syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That level of indirection you want is a little weird... the reason this doesn't work:

```
<div th:utext="#{${T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey}}"></div>
// Resolves to
<div th:utext="#{myKey1}"></div>
// Which isn't the actual message key since it's supposed to look like this:
<div th:utext="#{screen.home.welcome}"></div>
```

I probably wouldn't recommend it, but you could probably use preprocessing for this.  Something like this would probably work for you:

```
<div th:utext="#{${__${T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey}__}}"></div>
// Resolves to
<div th:utext="#{${myKey1}}"></div>
// Resolves to
<div th:utext="#{screen.home.welcome}"></div>
```

This would probably work as well:

```
<div th:utext="#{${#root.get(T(com.package.MyKeys).myKey)}}"></div>
```

Comment: Both solutions actually work! Thank you, I guess that I should choose the second one? Can you also include a brief note for why preprocessing is not recommended?

Comment: Preprocessing is dangerous because the value of `myKey` could potentially cause a runtime error.  The second would probably be better.